# Microsoft Jet OLEDB syntax error on UPDATE

Tags: mysql, database, oledb

I have a database similar to the one below:

```
Table1(AutoNumber, Text, Number, Memo) // this is field types
Table1(ID, Title, Price, Image)
```

I'm trying to update an existing element of the database in C# using:

```
const string connectionString = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "data source=bd.mdb";
OleDbConnection m_dataBase = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
OleDbConnection m_dataBase.Open();
SQL = "UPDATE Table1 SET Title='test', Price=35, Image='Test' WHERE ID=1";
OleDbCommand SQLQueryCommand = new OleDbCommand(SQL, m_dataBase);
int response = SQLQueryCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

As a result I am getting this error. "**Microsoft JET Database Engine Error syntax in UPDATE instruction**".

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I can successfully do `SELECT` or `INSERT`, but not `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your SQL command is the only problem, there are some visible issues.
Simply try to parametrize your Update clause using such as below which will prevent lots of little mistakes and also an SQL injection.

```
    SQL = "UPDATE Table1 SET Title=?, Price=?, Image=? WHERE ID=?";
    SQLQueryCommand.Parameter.Add("@MyTitle", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "Test"; 
    SQLQueryCommand.Parameter.Add("@MyPrice", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 35; 
    SQLQueryCommand.Parameter.Add("@MyImage", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "TestAgain"; 
    SQLQueryCommand.Parameter.Add("@MyID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = 1;
```

To learn more about parametrization try having a look at the example in the bottom of this MSDN article.

[OleDbCommand.Parameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also, it's a good practice to surround your connection inside a `using` statement.

```
using (var m_dataBase = new OleDbConnection(connectionString) { ... }
```